# Azure CDN Endpoint No Option To Set Caching Rules

Tags: azure, cloud, cdn

I am using Azure CDN with Azure Blob Storage to host my static website. However, when I want to configure my TTL of my CDN so that my website is updated immediately when I update my code, there is no option to configure my caching rules at all.

Image of what I see
https://i.stack.imgur.com/59qCv.png

Image of what it is supposed to be
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndCkd.png

Answer (score 1):

Caching rules are available only for **Azure CDN Standard from Verizon** and **Azure CDN Standard from Akamai profiles**. For **Azure CDN from Microsoft profiles**, you must use the **Standard rules engine** as shown below,

[image]

For **Azure CDN Premium from Verizon profiles**, you must use the Verizon Premium rules engine in the Manage portal for similar functionality.